# How does the shield work in Sunshine?

Tags: sunshine

The shield in the movie [Sunshine (2007, Danny Boyle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshine_%282007_film%29), appears to be made of "panels", that seem to move to face the Sun. How does it work? I mean, I know it's not exact science, but surely there was some design put into it. And what is the function of the "panels"?

Answer (score 4):

The [gold panels](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5756481_gold-used-space-equipment_.html) are intended to reflect [solar radiation](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_radiation) away from the ship so that it doesn't overheat or melt.

In reality, the [reflective surfaces alone will not protect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35225/how-close-can-spaceship-get-to-the-sun) a ship's inhabitants from solar radiation outside of the visible, ultraviolet, and infrared ranges, especially when that close to the sun--intense harmful radiation and strong tidal forces come into play at that point.

Comment: In the movie, you see the panels "flicker" when the shield rotates. At one point in the movie, two crew members have to manually fix 4 of these panels, which seem to have been left upright, or something. What's the point of having all these panels?

Comment: Why not use a single, big, layer of gold, instead of using all these panels?

Comment: @becko Because they could make a "dramatic" scene out of it and had another 5-10 minutes. If the story is bad, you have to invent stuff. (I don't like the movie because of its weeks story, like in this example.)

Comment: @becko Presumably it is easier to manufacture. I would assume they could not put a whole shield into orbit, so it was broken into panels. I don't know why the panels would raise or lower however.